# Python name 'servers' is not defined

Tags: python, pickle

I want to create a python script which checks if a server on a server is up or not. Rather if a server is up or not I want to catch that result in a file. In the end if a server is down then I want to receive an email.

I use the tutorial https://linuxhint.com/python-server-monitoring-script/ to start creating the python file with the below result.

When I execute the python file I get the below error. I not really familiar with working classes. So I hope you can help me out here.

```
$ C:/Users/../AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/python.exe c:/Users/.../Documents/git/CV%20Reader%20FastAPI/CheckServer.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/../Documents/git/CV%20Reader%20FastAPI/CheckServer.py",
line 77, in <module>
    servers.pickle.load(open("servers.pickle","rb"))
NameError: name 'servers' is not defined

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/../Documents/git/../CheckServer.py",r.py", line 80, in <module>
    Server("serveradres",80,"plain","high"),
  File "c:/Users/../Documents/git/../CheckServer.py",r.py", line 12, in __init__
    self.name
AttributeError: 'Server' object has no attribute 'name'
```

**CODE**

```
from os import system
import socket
import ssl
import pickle
from datetime import datetime, time
import subprocess
import platform

class Server():
    def __init__(self, name, port, connection, priority):
        self.name
        self.port
        self.connection
        self.priority
        
        self.history = []
        self.alert =  False

        def checkConnection(self):
            msg = ""
            succes = False
            now = datetime.now

            try:
                if self.connection == "plain":
                    socket.create_connection((self.name,self.port),timeout=10)
                    msg = f"{self.name} is up. On Port {self.port} with {self.connection}"
                    succes = True
                    self.alert = False
                elif self.connection == "ssl":
                    ssl.wrap_socket(socket.create_connection((self.name,self.port),timeout=10))
                    msg = f"{self.name} is up. On Port {self.port} with {self.connection}"
                    succes = True
                    self.alert = False
                elif succes == False and self.alert == False:
                    # Send Alert
                    self.alert = True
                    # email_alert(self.name,f"{msg}\n{now}","erik.hoeven@gmail.com")  
                else:
                    if self.ping():
                        msg = f"{self.name} Timout on Port {self.port} with {self.connection}"
                        succes = True
                        self.alert = False
                
                self.create_history(msg,succes,now)
            except socket.timeout:
                msg = f"{self.name} is Down. On Port {self.port}"
                succes = False
                alert = True
            
            except:
                pass

        def ping(self):
            try:
                output = subprocess.check_output("ping - {} 1 {}".format('n' if platform.system.lower() == 'windowns' else 'c', self.name), shell = True, universal_newlines = True)
                if 'unreachable'  in output:
                    return False
                
                else:
                    return True

            except Exception:
                return False

        def create_history(self,msg,succes,now):
            history_max = 100
            self.history.append((msg,succes,now))

            while len(self.history) > history_max:
                self.history.pop(0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        servers.pickle.load(open("servers.pickle","rb"))
    except:
        servers = [
        Server("servername1",80,"plain","high"),
        Server("servername2",5001,"plain","high")]
    for server in servers:
        server.checkConnection()
        print(len(server.history))
        print(server.history[-1])

    pickle.dump(servers,open("serfvers.pickle","wb"))
```

Comment: you are accessing `servers` inside the try, but you didn't declare before what it is supposed to be

Comment: Did you mean to write ``servers = pickle.load(...`` instead of ``servers.pickle.load(...``?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are getting is because in `Server.__init__()` you are trying to access the object attribute `name` instead of assigning to it the parameter with the same name. You are looking for:

```py
class Server():
    def __init__(self, name, port, connection, priority):
        self.name = name
        ...
```

The same applies to all the other parameters.

Also, there is a problem with indentation of member functions, as in the curent form of your code you are defining *local* functions instead of class member ones. To fix this, decrease indentation of the other (non-init) methods.